# How to replace all single characters from string?

Tags: xslt-2.0

```
<title>
<article_title>Land a b   c   d      Band a /article_title></article_title>
</title>

<xsl:value-of select='replace(article_title,"(\s+.\s+)"," ")'/>
```

I am expecting Land Band but instead I'm getting land b d band.
Can someone correct the replace function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use**:

```
replace(article_title, '(^[^ ]+)(.+\s+)([^ ]+)$', '$1 $3')
```

**Here is a complete transformation**:

```
 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:value-of select=
  "replace(article_title, '(^[^ ]+)(.+\s+)([^ ]+)$', '$1 $3')"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<title>
    <article_title>Land a b   c   d      Band</article_title>
</title>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
Land Band
```

Comment: Dimitre, thanks. Can i get a solution for this in xslt 1.0 without the use of replace function.

Comment: @sanjay -- Yes, XSLT 1.0 is Turing complete. However the solution will be much more complicated, because XSLT 1.0 lacks RegEx support. For text processing in XSLT 1.0 I often use the FXSL library, that offers convenient set of templates/functions and Higher - Order - Functions (HOF). In case you are interested, please ask a new question and this time don't use the xslt-2.0 tag (specifying the xslt-1.0 tag will be appropriate).